# BigQuery ignoring --use_avro_logical_types flag while loading data with AVRO format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, avro

I have AVRO data with following fields where created_at & updated_at is a TIMESTAMP column which is represented in AVRO Logical Type that converted it into LONG.

AVRO Schema:

```
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- account_manager_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- total_sales_existing_accounts: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- total_sales_new_accounts: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- qtr_start_date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- qtr_end_date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |-- total_sales_with_contact: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- total_sales: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- total_sales_percentage_compared_to_previous: integer (nullable = true)
```

So, while loading this file to BigQuery I want the BigQuery table should have TIMESTAMP column and not INTEGER column having UNIX EPOC TIMESTAMP.

As per the BigQuery documentation, I am setting `--use_avro_logical_types` this flag to `True` while loading data.

```
bq --location=US load --source_format=AVRO --use_avro_logical_types=True writable.test_account_stat gs://test-bucket/production/avro/account_quarter_sales_stats/*.avro
```

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types)

But the `--use_avro_logical_types=True` is ignored and my BigQuery table is having these date columns as INTEGER.

I tried with API as well as command line as per the following documentation but no luck :(

Comment: I have observed same issue using --use_avro_logical_types flag, but if you create BQ table with TIMESTAMP datatype manually you will be able to load data into it.

Comment: I have around 1200+ table which gets created dynamically by loading Avro files using `WRITE_TRUNCATE` disposition every day. So, it is not feasible to create every table manually and the table structure might change anytime.